# sql query translate to spark lang in zeppelin

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I try to tranfer sql query to spark lang. Here is the sql query:

```
%sql
select ${checkbox:fields=AGE|NAME|SEX} from table limit ${limit=10}
```

Then I transfer spark lang:

```
%spark
var fields = z.select("fields", Seq(("AGE","AGE"),("NAME","NAME"),("SEX","SEX"))
val lim = z.input("limit","20")
df.selectExpr(fields).limit(lim).show()
```

but it does not work. How to collect it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try? What did you research? Your post is clear, but it is not showing too much work from your side (just one trial).

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that you have missed here.

- In sql you are using checkbox while in scala/spark you are using select. In checkbox you can select multiple values while in select you can select only 1 value. In rest of answer I am assuming you want to do multiple selection.
- Try this in scala:

```
 val f = z.checkbox("fields", options).to[collection.immutable.Seq]
 val lim = z.input("limit","20").asInstanceOf[String].toInt
 //Assuming df is already defined
 df.selectExpr(f.map(c => (c+"")): _*).limit(lim).show()
 df.select(f.map(c => col(c+"")): _*).limit(lim).show()
```

z.input returns an object. limit in spark DF takes Int as input, so we have converted it to Int. 
z.checkbox returns scala.collection.Iterable, while selectExpr/select needs the input in different types.